# For each line of an ifstream, ofstream to a file. Garbage saved in them?

Tags: c++, iteration, ifstream, stringstream, ofstream

I'm trying to open an ifstream and then use the information in the input file, manipulate it and save the results to new .txt file for each line.

I'm getting the right thing when I cout it, but garbage in my .txt files.

Is this not legal? Do I have to follow the Ghostbusters rule and not cross the streams? I thought it work because they were different streams, but maybe I was wrong? I searched and couldn't find an answer to this.

Is there a better way to do this that I'm not thinking about?

Yes, this is HW. Thanks you for any help you have for me!

```
ifstream userFile;              // Open the input file
string line;    
userFile.open(filename.c_str());

if(!userFile)
    {
    cerr << "Can't open input file.\n";
    }

while (getline(userFile, line))
    {

    istringstream ss(line);

    //...... (DO STUFF TO THE LINE HERE)


                    // Here we are creating the file to write to.

    ofstream lineOutFile;

    string newFileName;

    stringstream linefile;
    linefile << lineCt;
    linefile >> newFileName;

    newFileName += ".txt";

    lineOutFile.open(newFileName.c_str(), ios::out);

    if(!lineOutFile)
        {
        cerr << "Can't open output file.\n";
        }

lineOutFile << "            •Original line of sequence - " << origLine;

lineOutFile << "\n\nThe corrected 5' x 3' complement of line " << lineCt << " is as follows - \n\n" << finalSeq << "\n\n\n" << "This line of DNA sequence is made up of " << cgContent << " C and G neucleotides.\n\n" << "It contains " << polyTCount << " Poly-T strings of more than 4 consecutive neucleotides.\n";

if(polyTCount > 0)
    lineOutFile << "They are as follows. - \n" <<  polyTString;

lineOutFile << "\nThere are " << cpgCount << " CpG sites.";

if(cpgCount > 0)
    lineOutFile << "The locations are as follows - \n" << cpgString;

    lineOutFile.close();    

    lineCt++;

    }

userFile.close();

}
```

The files do open correctly (1.txt 2.txt 3.txt... etc), but with garbage in them.

Comment: It seems like you didn't include the most important parts in the question and you have put (OUTPUT TO THE FILE) and such instead.

Comment: It was just a really long string of stuff, didn't want to confuse my main question. I added it back in.

Comment: When you say there's garbage on the files, what do you actually mean?  Show some sample output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ofstream returning garbage. Cout works... Why doesn't ofstream?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597241/ofstream-returning-garbage-cout-works-why-doesnt-ofstream)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at least the basic idea of what you're doing is allowed, supported, and works with every C++ compiler I've used.

Quick demo:

```
int main(){ 
    std::istringstream in("one\ntwo\nthree");

    std::string line;

    for (int i = 1; in >> line; i++) {
        std::ofstream out(lexical_cast<std::string>(i) + ".txt");
        out << line;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
1.txt:
one

2.txt:
two

3.txt:
three
```