# Ofstream returning garbage. Cout works... Why doesn't ofstream?

Tags: c++, fstream, cout, stringstream, ostream

So I'm trying to design a program that inputs a file and then reads through the lines and takes each line and outputs info about it to a new file.

I have it all down... except! All my .txt files are filled with garbage instead of what they should be filled with.

I can not figure it out. If I cout the string I'm feeding into the ofstream, the right stuff prints on the screen.

```
fstream lineOutFile;
string newFileName;
stringstream linefile;

linefile << lineCt;
linefile >> newFileName;

newFileName += ".txt";

lineOutFile.open(newFileName.c_str());

if(!lineOutFile)
{
    cerr << "Can't open output file.\n";
}

stringstream iss;
iss << "The corrected 5' x 3' complement of line " << lineCt <<
    " is as follows - \n\n" << finalSeq << "\n\n\n\n" <<
    "This line of DNA sequence is made up of " << cgContent <<
    " C and G neucleotides.\n\n" << "It contains " << polyTCount <<
    " Poly-T strings of more than 4 consecutive neucleotides. They are as follows. - \n" <<
    polyTString << "\n\n There are " << cpgCount <<
    " CpG sites. The locations are as follows - \n" << cpgString;

string storage;
storage = iss.str();
cout << storage;
lineOutFile << storage;
lineOutFile.close();
lineCt++;

}
```

I'm getting "⁥潣牲捥整⁤✵砠㌠‧" << This sort of craziness in my .txt files.

I get the right thing when I cout out the same sting immediately before!

Why are my .txt files garbage?

Comment: Can it be that you interpret your .txt files as Unicode (UTF-16) when reading them? Then you will see that garbage (although in a 8-bit encoding this would look correctly).

Comment: How would I be able to tell? It looks like my input file is Unicode (UTF-8). Is that right?

Comment: What text editor are you using?

Comment: Gedit. I'm just pulling up a text document through terminal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `fstream` instead of `ofstream`?

The default for `fstream` is to open an existing file.  The default for `ofstream` is to start with an empty file.  Whatever is already in the file is probably causing your editor to interpret the data with the wrong encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
LANG=C your_program
```

And turn off encoding recognition in your editor. Even better - view your txt files with `cat` program.